# Probability of two scenarios happening (I think dependent scenarios)

Tags: probability

The probability of an engine failure in the first year is 0.25.

The probably of the engine NOT failing in the next three years is 0.6.

What is the probability of the engine failing in the first four years?

Comment: Welcome to math.se. Here are some tips on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- The engine fails in ONLY the first year
- The engine fails in ONLY the next three years
- The engine fails in BOTH the first and next three years

Case 1 comes out to $0.25\cdot 0.6$.

Case 2 comes out to $0.75 \cdot 0.4$, since the probability of the engine failing in the 3 years is $1-0.6 = 0.4$.

Case 3 comes out to $0.25\cdot 0.4$.

Adding them up gets $\boxed{0.55.}$

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $.25+.75\times .4=.55$